# Is it possible to store a push notification in Firebase sent without the console?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-notifications

Like the title says, I'm searching of a way to store a push notification sent by an HTTP request from my own back-end on Node.js, to the Firebase database (with [fcm app server protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)).

Actually, I can send a push notification to my device using requestify.
I just want to know how I can list them in the [Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLCAi.png).

Is there any way to achieve this ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: unfortunately I don't think there is a way to add manual entries to the messaging console archives.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i think also. We should keep this post opened in case a feature is added in the future.